# CheckedTextview not checkable

Tags: android, android-listview, checkedtextview

Can't get my checkedtextview to check or do anything for that matter. When I touch the listitem it doesn't do anything, it's not clickable. 
I've tried to add itemclicklistener to the listview but it didn't work.
Am I missing something? or is it another way to do this?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


DatabaseReference databaseItems;




TextView itemlist;
ListView listitem;
ImageView addlistitem;

List<Items> listitems;


{

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseItems = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items");



    itemlist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvitemlist);

    listitem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvitemlist);

    ArrayAdapter<Items> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Items>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
    itemlist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    listitem.setAdapter(adapter);




    listitem.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    listitem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseItems.orderByChild("items").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listitems.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot itemsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                final Items items = itemsSnapshot.getValue(Items.class);

                listitems.add(items);

                final listItems adapter = new listItems(MainActivity.this, listitem);
                listitem.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();









            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });

}
```

Adapter:

```
public class listItems extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

private Activity context;
private List<Items> listitems;

public listItems(Activity context, List<Items> listitems){
    super (context, R.layout.list_items, listitems);
    this.context = context;
    this.listitems = listitems;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, true);

    final Items items = listitems.get(position);

    final TextView tvitemname = (CheckedTextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvitemname);
    tvitemname.setText(item.getItemname());
    ((CheckedTextView) tvitemname).setChecked(listitems.get(position).setSelected(true));

    tvitemname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(((CheckedTextView) tvjitemname).isChecked()) {
                items.setSelected(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                items.setSelected(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

Model class:

```
public class Items {

String itemId;
String itemname;
private boolean IsSelected;

public Items(String itemId, String itemname, boolean isSelected) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    IsSelected = isSelected;
}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public String getItemname() {
    return itemname;
}



public boolean isSelected() {
    return IsSelected;
}

public boolean setSelected(boolean selected) {
    IsSelected = selected;
    return false;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:id="@+id/tvitemname"
    android:checkMarkTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `CheckBox` or any other  `CompoundButton`, you need to call `setCheck` to toggle state on `CheckedTextView` whenever it is clicked:

```
    if (((CheckedTextView) tvjitemname).isChecked()) {
        tvjitemname.setChecked(false);
        items.setSelected(false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        tvjitemname.setChecked(true);
        items.setSelected(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And also by the way, this line looks wrong:

```
// Wrong
((CheckedTextView) tvitemname).setChecked(listitems.get(position).setSelected(true));
```

It should be:

```
((CheckedTextView) tvitemname).setChecked(listitems.get(position).isSelected();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, but it's still not clickable, so something else has to be wrong in my code:/

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure if `listitems.setItemsCanFocus(true)` has something to do with it, the initial state should be false. Or if you could post your `R.layout.list_items` layout so I could have a look, otherwise your code should work. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Alex Umm.. sorry I found another problem with your code, you called `setSelected` instead of `isSelect` when you're binding the view, please check my answer.

Comment: I manage to click on one item now, but it doesn't click at once, it takes time for it to be checked (delay or something). And I can't check more than one item at once. I can edit with my list_items layout :)

Comment: @Alex Oh what do you mean by delay? Other than the delay, did it work as you expect?

Comment: It just got checked when I pressed alot of times. I'm using firebase, maybe it has something to do with that? In my database base now it has a new ischecked child that is always set to "true".

Comment: I'm not sure without looking at the actual implementation. Maybe somewhere in your code is updating the adapter, or maybe you need to optimize your  code in `getView`, or it could be other factor that's in your code blocking UI thread.

Comment: I have edited my MainActivity. There you can see my code.

Comment: Maybe your database is also listening to data changes, you could try removing `notifyDataSetChanged` from `getView`.

Comment: This worked :) Thank you! Now it's checkable. But is it possible to save the values, that when I reset my app, it will show the same values that it did before the reset?

Comment: I assume they can, but sorry I'm not exactly sure about that, you might have to check with Firebase database documentation or open a new question.

Comment: Could please you mark this answer if it has helped you resolving the clicking issues on `CheckedTextView`?